# Why I must type something after cat << to make it work?

Tags: bash, scripting, cat

I've seen questions about cat << EOF so it's not duplicate.

If I do:

```
piotr@thinkpad:~$ cat <<
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

I have error but when I do:

```
piotr@thinkpad:~$ cat << iudshfsfa
>
```

where **iudshfsfa** are random letters, it works

Comment: `<< word` introduces a here-doc; `word` is required, can be any number of different strings (not just `EOF`), and its absence is a syntax error.

Comment: "Why" ... can mostly answered only by  "because that's how it was when it was developed". Whoever developed it might have decided they needed a way to signal an end to the heredoc, and having that signal be set by the start seems a elegant and flexible way.

Comment: First, this has (almost) nothing to do with `cat`. Second, the first case doesn’t work simply because it doesn’t conform to the Bash grammar, i.e., doesn’t parse as valid Bash code. So Bash doesn’t know what to do with it. The second example starts a here-doc, i.e., Bash will take all input it sees, until it encounters `iudshfsfa` alone on a separate line, at which point it will send the input to `cat` (which will, as expected, print it out).